# Why does my program return inaccurate result?

Tags: matlab, fortran, subroutine

I wrote the well-known [spectral-norm algorithm](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/performance/spectralnorm.html) in Fortran after I initially wrote (and optimized) it in MATLAB. The speedup after naive conversion to Fortran is at least 18X, but the problem is that the output of the Fortran program is not accurate. The correct output should be `1.274224153` but my Fortran program outputs `1.273722712`, what am I doing wrong in Fortran?

```
program perf_spectralnorm
implicit none
integer, parameter :: n = 5500, dp = kind(0.d0) 
real(dp) :: u(n) = 1, v(n), w(n), vBv, vv, res
integer  :: i, j, nvec(n)

nvec = [(i, i=1,n)]
do i = 1,10
   call Au(w, u)   ! change w
   call Atu(v, w)  ! change v
   call Au(w, v)   ! change w
   call Atu(u, w)  ! change u
end do
vBv = dot_product(u, v) 
vv  = dot_product(v, v)
res = sqrt(vBv/vv)

print '(f12.9)', res

contains 

elemental real(dp) function A(i, j)
   integer, intent(in) :: i, j
   A = 1.0_dp / ((i+j) * (i+j+1.0_dP)/2 + i + 1)
end

subroutine Au(w, u)
   real(dp) :: w(:), u(:)  
   do i = 1,n 
      w(i) = dot_product(A(i-1,nvec-1) , u)  
   end do
end

subroutine Atu(v, w)
   real(dp) :: v(:), w(:)     
   do i = 1,n  
      v(i) = dot_product(A(nvec-1,i-1) , w)       
   end do
end

end program perf_spectralnorm
```

My original implementation in MATLAB with correct output is as follows:

```
n = 5500; 
fprintf("%.9f\n", perf_spectralnorm(n))

function res = A(i,j) 
    res = 1 ./ ((i+j) .* (i+j+1)/2 + i + 1);
end

function w = Au(u,w)
    n = length(u);
    j = 1:n;
    for i = 1:n         
        w(i) = dot( A(i-1,j-1), u );
    end
end

function v = Atu(w,v)
    n = length(w);
    j = 1:n;
    for i = 1:n         
        v(i) = dot( A(j-1,i-1), w );
    end
end

function res = perf_spectralnorm(n)
    u = ones(n,1);
    v = zeros(n,1);
    w = zeros(n,1);
    for i = 1:10
        w = Au(u,w);
        v = Atu(w,v);
        w = Au(v,w);
        u = Atu(w,u);
    end
    vBv = dot(u,v);
    vv  = dot(v,v);
    res = sqrt(vBv/vv);
end
```

Comment: What Fortran compiler are you using, and have you turned on all debugging features?   With gfortran and -fcheck=all -Wall, I get a runtime error "At line 8 of file a.f90
Fortran runtime error: Loop variable has been modified"

Comment: Yep, subroutines Au and Atu USE variable `i` via host association.  You need to locally declare `i` in these routines.

Comment: @evets -- Thank you very much, you are right, I tend to use implicit variables (very bad habit) inside subroutines. In my case, the value of `I` in the main program propagated its value to the called subroutines. Please go a head and write an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subroutines `Au` and `Atu` use a variable `i` for the do-loop through host association.  This modified the do-loop variable `i` in main program, which is invalid.  To solve the issue, you need to declare `i` as a local variable in `Au` and `Atu`.  For example,

```
subroutine Au(w, u)
     real(dp), intent(out) :: w(:)
     real(dp), intent(in)  :: u(:)
     integer i
     do i = 1, n 
        w(i) = dot_product(A(nvec-1,i-1), u)  
     end do
  end
```

Note, I've taken the liberty to also include the `INTENT` of the dummy arguments.

Comment: I've done some tests and, by making `nvec` a `parameter`, I got a 33% speed-up with `gfortran -Ofast` comparing with the presented solution. I have 3.39sec with my not-that-impressive i5 - 1.6GHz. The same result is obtained by using only array implied-do constructors instead of `do`loops and `nvec`.